# MEF: Any way to conditionally select an export prior to class construction?

Tags: c#, mef

I have two implementations of an `ISchedulerProvider` interface, one for test purposes and one for non-test execution (compliments of Lee Campbell's [Intro to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/16_TestingRx.html#SchedulerDI)). I would like to export both instances via MEF and handle the imports such that, if I detect I'm in a test environment, use the test scheduler, and if I'm not, then use the other one.

I could set metadata on each export, use an `[ImportMany]` everywhere I use the `ISchedulerProvider` with a corresponding filter, but that seems like a lot of overhead.  Is there any way to conditionally select between exports prior to class construction?

A simple example would be very helpful, particularly if the solution involves something like an export provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a class that inherits from CompositionContainer that filters out exports based on a custom attribute.

Here's an example I've thrown together:

Interface to implement

```
public interface ISchedulerProvider
{
    string Foo { get; }
}
```

Custom Attribute to hold target environment info, I used strings in this example but I'd probably use an Enum in production code:

```
public class EnvironmentSpecificAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string TargetEnvironment { get; }

    public EnvironmentSpecificAttribute(string targetEnvironment)
    {
        TargetEnvironment = targetEnvironment;
    }
}
```

Example implementations:

```
[EnvironmentSpecific("QA")]
[Export(typeof(ISchedulerProvider))]
public class TestProvider : ISchedulerProvider
{
    public string Foo { get; } = "TestBar";
}

[EnvironmentSpecific("Prod")]
[Export(typeof(ISchedulerProvider))]
public class RealProvider : ISchedulerProvider
{
    public string Foo { get; } = "RealBar";
}
```

Class to consume interface:

```
[Export]
public class Consumer
{
    private readonly ISchedulerProvider _schedulerProvider;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Consumer(ISchedulerProvider schedulerProvider)
    {
        _schedulerProvider = schedulerProvider;
    }

    public string GetFoo()
    {
        return _schedulerProvider.Foo;
    }
}
```

Custom CompositionContainer:

```
public class EnvironmentSpecificContainer : CompositionContainer
{
    private readonly string _targetEnvironment;

    public EnvironmentSpecificContainer(ComposablePartCatalog catalog, string targetEnvironment, params ExportProvider[] providers) : base(catalog, providers)
    {
        _targetEnvironment = targetEnvironment;
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Export> GetExportsCore(ImportDefinition definition, AtomicComposition atomicComposition)
    {
        return base.GetExportsCore(definition, atomicComposition)?.Where(IsForEnvironmentOrEnvironmentNotSpecified);
    }

    private bool IsForEnvironmentOrEnvironmentNotSpecified(Export export)
    {
        EnvironmentSpecificAttribute attribute = export.Value.GetType().GetCustomAttribute<EnvironmentSpecificAttribute>() as EnvironmentSpecificAttribute;
        return attribute == null || string.Equals(attribute.TargetEnvironment, _targetEnvironment,
                   StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Finally, the usage of the above classes:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string environmentName = "QA";
    EnvironmentSpecificContainer container = new EnvironmentSpecificContainer(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()), environmentName);

    var tmp = container.GetExportedValue<object>("MefTest.Consumer");
}
```

Comment: Great answer, I think this is exactly what I need.  Do you know if GetExportsCore will be called if I use Compose(...) instead of GetExportedValue?

Comment: I guess you could accomplish the same with [SharingBoundary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.composition.sharedattribute.sharingboundary?view=dotnet-plat-ext-2.1#System_Composition_SharedAttribute_SharingBoundary) in `Mef2`.